# Regex for password = one number and both lower and uppercase letters and special characters BUT!! no special characters at start or end

Tags: regex, passwords

I'm trying to create a Regex for an html5 pattern in a password input.

The password must contain at least:

- 1 uppercase letter
- 1 lowercase letter
- 1 number
- 1 special character
- 8-20 characters
- Must not start or end with a special character

Any help appreciated

Comment: Don't validate a password in HTML. That's pretty much the worst place you could do this.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why can't your passwords start/end with a special character? This seems like **really** weird logic to me.

Comment: It’s only inline validation. Server side will take care of the heavy lifting. With regards to the why of a special character at the end or beginning... sorry no clue, they haven’t told me the reasons.

Comment: You and your team should take a look at [Reference - Password Validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48345922/).

Comment: If you *need* to do some sort of validation client side just use AJAX to call your server-side validation script. No need to create 2 regular expressions. Anything you do in HTML patterns right now can be undone and they also don't allow Unicode if you're using `[a-z]` to ensure lowercase letters (same goes for uppercase letters, numbers and special characters. Adding the *logic* that doesn't allow a password to begin and end with a special character also reduces the number of potential passwords, thus making your systems less secure. Your team should definitely re-evaluate password policies.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not that hard:

```
(                   # Start of group
    (?=.*\d)        #   must contain at least one digit
    (?=.*[A-Z])     #   must contain at least one uppercase character
    (?=.*[a-z])     #   must contain at least one lowercase character
    (?=.*\W)        #   must contain at least one special symbol
    \w
       .            #   match anything with previous condition checking
        {6,18}      #   length is  characters
    \w 
)                   # End of group
```

In one line:

```
((?=.*\d)(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*\W)\w.{6,18}\w)
```

If you do not like `\w` which is equal to `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` replace it with that group and remove the underscore.

However, I fully support ctwheels' argument.